# JavaScript Title as Caption doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, titlebar

I've being trying to implement a simple slider, but I wanted to have the title of my different div tags to be used as caption for each category of the product. But for some reason, the function only shows the title of the first div and doesn't chenge. How do I correct it?

Here's what I've added:

```
$('.next').click(function(){
$('#titlebox').text($('.room').attr('title'));
});
```

to the end of this script:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVBvRO.

Basically, what I want to achieve is to insert a caption to a product (which is displayed) in a div above the slider. If there is an alternative to what I've tried, like getElementsbyID - please help me to write it too! As long as it gets the job done =)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:nth-child()` selector and pass in your `currentIndex`:

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    $('#titlebox').text($('.room:nth-child('+currentIndex+')').attr('title'));
});
```

Note that `:nth-child()` starts with `:nth-child(1)`. So you will want to use `(currentIndex + 1)` or have `currentIndex` a minimum value of `1`.

Here is an [**example codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNRKjW), with the same functionality added to `$('.prev').click` to show that it works.

Comment: Nice, it work! However, why doesn't it show a title immediately? And what's a way to fix it?

Comment: @Tony That's because it's only showing when the buttons are clicked. Add it to the `document.ready` function like so: `$(function(){ /*code to show title*/ });`. And it will show up immediately. [Here is an example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdJoQq).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```js
$('.demo').on('click', function(e) {
  var title = $(items[currentIndex]).attr('title');
  if ($(e.target).hasClass('next') && title) {
    $('#titlebox').text(title);
  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/godban/pen/QbZmxz

Comment: I cant - not enough reputation so far! I would love to tho! Sorry! =(